# file-roller: An error occurred while loading the archive (Zip/7z)

Tags: zip, archive, strace, 7z, file-roller

As I don't use GUI for archive extraction much, I don't know since when this error I am getting:

> ```
> An error occurred while loading the archive.
> ```

This error I get while trying to open an ordinary [Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) and / or [7z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z) archives, but I care only about [Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) in this question.

I am able to open [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar).[bz2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2) and [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar).[gz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) files, though.

As a side note: *This is particularly annoying as I started using Thunderbird for mail and so I intend to open all attachments in GUI.*

[OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment): [Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon 64-bit](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=226).

Version of Archive manager for GNOME:

```
/usr/bin/file-roller --version
```

> ```
> file-roller 3.16.5, Copyright © 2001-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> ```

Example:

A file downloaded from GitHub from this page as [Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)): [TrueColour.md](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728)

For convenience renamed to `truecolor.zip`.

```
file truecolor.zip
```

says it is an ordinary [Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) archive:

> ```
> truecolor.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
> ```

```
file-roller truecolor.zip
```

run from terminal says the above error message with no output to the terminal.

Sure though, I am able to decompress it with:

```
unzip truecolor.zip
```

with output:

> ```
> Archive:  truecolor.zip
> f8e6e08a0f0d3ad09e599a4f17edc010d38e4ec8
>    creating: 8346728-f8e6e08a0f0d3ad09e599a4f17edc010d38e4ec8/
>   inflating: 8346728-f8e6e08a0f0d3ad09e599a4f17edc010d38e4ec8/TrueColour.md
> ```

**EDIT1:**

I have managed to get some, possibly useful, debug info using:

```
strace -t -f file-roller truecolor.zip 2> fileroller-open-zip-strace
```

As it is rather lengthy, it won't fit into Pastebin, so I have compressed it, SHA-256 hash follows:

> ```
> 4f09bc1f16c0e618cfd6937946db23a18be8e5e1fb1b8d4930ead49af5e77abb
> ```

You may download it from my hosting:

https://www.vlastimilburian.cz/fileroller-open-zip-strace.bz2

The above file has been deleted.

If someone knows what to look for in the `strace`'s output, I am sure he / she would find the relevant part, but I sadly don't know what to look for.

**EDIT2:**

Latest available version on GitHub, compiled:

```
./file-roller --version
```

> ```
> file-roller 3.22.2, Copyright © 2001-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> ```

run from terminal:

```
./file-roller ~/Downloads/truecolor.zip
```

shows the very same error message:

> ```
> An error occurred while loading the archive.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to self-compile the `p7zip` package, now everything works as usual.

I tried purging `p7zip-full` and installing it back, but that didn't do anything, I still wonder why. Nevermind, solution was to build the package myself, I should have done that long time ago.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you.

Finally, I've found an old `7z` shell script in `bin` directory, that claimed to launch the `7z` executable from an incorrect path.

After removing this wrong script, the problem was solved.

So, check your shell aliases and personal shell scripts, in order to discover any error concerning programs used by `file-roller` application to manage the archive file types.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same error on a new install of Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon trying to open files I'd created with an older version of Mint (14?).  I discovered that I only had the "light" version installed with the distro and had to install "p7zip-full" to get encryption support. Did that and the files open as they should now.